# Can you convert a sql case statement to crystal syntax?

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports

I have a sql case statement that is working beautifully. I am trying to get the same thing to work in a Crystal report. The biggest issue is I need the report to add only the difference of two conditions, which I can't seem to make work in Crystal.

SQL:

```
 select sum(case when type='PA' and tax_year=2022 then amt else 0 end) +                 
        sum((case when type='UN' and tax_year in (0, 2022) then amt else 0 end) - (case when type='RA' then amt else 0 end)) -     
        sum(case when type='DR' and tax_year in (0,2022) then amt else 0 end) +                                                                                                                               
        sum(case when type='CR' and tax_year=2022 then amt else 0 end) as total   
 From ar                                                                                           
 where date_ between '7/1/2021' and '6/30/2022' and source='PT'
```

I have a year formula already in Crystal to total them in the appropriate year "buckets", so I am trying to get the types to work.

CRYSTAL:

```
If {AR.TYPE}='PA' then {AR.AMT}
else if {AR.TYPE}='DR' then -{AR.AMT}
else if {AR.TYPE}='CR' then {AR.AMT}
else if {AR.TYPE}='OP' then -{AR.AMT}
**else if {AR.TYPE}='UN' then ({AR.AMT} - if {AR.TYPE}='RA' then {AR.AMT})** 
else {AR.AMT}
```

The bold piece above is giving me a difficult time.

I want the formula to add only the difference between all AR.TYPE='UN' and AR.TYPE='RA' but the Crystal formula I have above is just adding all UNs and ignoring the RAs

Answer (score 0):

Use this logic:

```
If {AR.TYPE}='PA' then {AR.AMT}
else if {AR.TYPE}='DR' then -{AR.AMT}
else if {AR.TYPE}='CR' then {AR.AMT}
else if {AR.TYPE}='OP' then -{AR.AMT}
else if {AR.TYPE}='UN' then {AR.AMT} 
else if {AR.TYPE}='RA' then -{AR.AMT}
else {AR.AMT}
```